# Flexboxで隣り合う要素の高さが揃ってしまう

Tags: html, css, sass

### 質問内容

左側のメニューのlabelを押すと、右側のメインメニューが干渉して動き、灰色の背景が現れます。
原因は分かりましたが、理由と対処法がわかりません。
よろしくお願いします。
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akatsuki1910/oh67vk8m/)

### コード

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="main-all-wrap">
        <div class="index-all-wrap">
            <div class="profile">
                <div class="profile-box">
                    <img src="#" class="trim-image-to-circle">
                    <div class="pro-name">a</div>
                    <div class="pro-text">
                        afa
                    </div>
                    <div class="pro-link">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram-square"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="pro-menu">
                    <label for="menu_bar1">label1</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="menu_bar1">
                    <ul id="links1">
                        <li><a href="#">Link01</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link02</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <label for="menu_bar2">label2</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="menu_bar2">
                    <ul id="links2">
                        <li><a href="#">Link01</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link02</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <label for="menu_bar3">label3</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="menu_bar3">
                    <ul id="links3">
                        <li><a href="#">Link01</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link02</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <label for="menu_bar4">label4</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="menu_bar4">
                    <ul id="links4">
                        <li><a href="#">Link01</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link02</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <label for="menu_bar5">label5</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="menu_bar5">
                    <ul id="links5">
                        <li><a href="#">Link01</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link02</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <label for="menu_bar6">label6</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="menu_bar6">
                    <ul id="links6">
                        <li><a href="#">Link01</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link02</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-contents-wrap">
                <div class="contents-main">
                    <img src="#">
                    <div class="main-title">{$maintitle}</div>
                    <div class="sub-title">{$subtitle}</div>
                    <div class="sub-title">{$subtitle}</div>
                    <div class="main-text">{$maintext}</div>
                    <a href="#" target="_self"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="contents-main">
                    <img src="#">
                    <div class="main-title">{$maintitle}</div>
                    <div class="sub-title">{$subtitle}</div>
                    <div class="sub-title">{$subtitle}</div>
                    <div class="main-text">{$maintext}</div>
                    <a href="#" target="_self"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```
@mixin center() {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

@mixin flexcenter() {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

$header-height:100px;
$menu-box-wigth:400px;
$pic-size-width:400px;
$pic-size-height:300px;

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
}

.main-all-wrap {
    margin-top: $header-height;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.index-all-wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

$profile-width:25vmin;

.profile {
    width: $profile-width;

    .profile-box {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: red;

        .trim-image-to-circle {
            width: calc(#{$profile-width} - 2px);
            height: calc(#{$profile-width} - 2px);
            border-radius: 50%;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        .pro-name {
            font-size: 2rem;
        }

        .pro-text {
            word-break: break-all;
        }

        .pro-link {
            font-size: 2rem;

            a {
                color: black;
                text-decoration: none;

                :visited,
                :hover {
                    color: black;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    .pro-menu {
        width: $profile-width;

        a {
            display: block;
            padding: 15px;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #000;
        }

        ul {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background: #f4f4f4;
            list-style: none;
        }

        li {
            height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            transition: all 0.5s;
        }

        input {
            display: none;
        }

        label {
            display: block;
            margin: 0 0 4px 0;
            padding: 15px; //To Do 原因
            line-height: 1;
            color: #fff;
            background: green;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        @for $i from 1 through 7 {
            #menu_bar#{$i}:checked~#links#{$i} li {
                height: calc(15px *2 + 1rem + 4px);
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
    }
}


.main-contents-wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;

    .contents-main {
        width: calc(100% - 20px);
        max-width: $pic-size-width + 200px;
        margin: 5px 10px;
        position: relative;
        background-color: #999999;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: 20% 20% calc(#{$pic-size-width} - 40%);
        grid-template-columns: $pic-size-width 1fr;

        img {
            grid-row: 1 /span 3;
            grid-column: 1;
            min-width: $pic-size-width;
            max-width: $pic-size-width;
            min-height: $pic-size-height;
            max-height: $pic-size-height;
            object-fit: cover;
            background-color: black;
        }

        .main-title {
            grid-row: 1;
            grid-column: 2;
            font-size: 2rem;
            max-height: calc(#{$pic-size-height} * 0.2);
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
            word-wrap: break-word;
        }

        .sub-title {
            grid-row: 2;
            grid-column: 2;
            font-size: large;
            max-height: calc(#{$pic-size-height} * 0.2);
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
            word-wrap: break-word;
        }

        .main-text {
            grid-row: 3;
            grid-column: 2;
            max-height: calc(#{$pic-size-height} * 0.6);
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
            word-wrap: break-word;
        }

        a {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問文のコードを読むと、 `.profile` と `.main-contents-wrap` を横並びにするために `.index-all-wrap` で `display: flex` を使用しています。ここで、 flexbox で使用される `align-items` プロパティは**初期値が `stretch`** であるため、 `.profile` と `.main-contents-wrap` の**高さが自動的に揃えられる**とわかります。このため、メニューをクリックし、メニューの高さがメインコンテンツより大きくなると、メニューと高さを合わせるために、メインコンテンツに灰色の領域が生じます。

以上から、この問題を解決するには、 `align-items` プロパティに対して `stretch` 以外の値を適用すれば良いことになります。たとえば、以下のように `align-items: start` を適用すると問題が解消していることが確認出来ます。

```
.index-all-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: start; // 追加
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.main-all-wrap {
  margin-top: 100px;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.index-all-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: start; /* 追加 */
}

.profile {
  width: 25vmin;
}
.profile .profile-box {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
.profile .profile-box .trim-image-to-circle {
  width: calc(25vmin - 2px);
  height: calc(25vmin - 2px);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.profile .profile-box .pro-name {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.profile .profile-box .pro-text {
  word-break: break-all;
}
.profile .profile-box .pro-link {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.profile .profile-box .pro-link a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.profile .profile-box .pro-link a :visited,
.profile .profile-box .pro-link a :hover {
  color: black;
}
.profile .pro-menu {
  width: 25vmin;
}
.profile .pro-menu a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
.profile .pro-menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  list-style: none;
}
.profile .pro-menu li {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.profile .pro-menu input {
  display: none;
}
.profile .pro-menu label {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 4px 0;
  padding: 15px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #fff;
  background: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.profile .pro-menu #menu_bar1:checked ~ #links1 li {
  height: calc(15px *2 + 1rem + 4px);
  opacity: 1;
}
.profile .pro-menu #menu_bar2:checked ~ #links2 li {
  height: calc(15px *2 + 1rem + 4px);
  opacity: 1;
}
.profile .pro-menu #menu_bar3:checked ~ #links3 li {
  height: calc(15px *2 + 1rem + 4px);
  opacity: 1;
}
.profile .pro-menu #menu_bar4:checked ~ #links4 li {
  height: calc(15px *2 + 1rem + 4px);
  opacity: 1;
}
.profile .pro-menu #menu_bar5:checked ~ #links5 li {
  height: calc(15px *2 + 1rem + 4px);
  opacity: 1;
}
.profile .pro-menu #menu_bar6:checked ~ #links6 li {
  height: calc(15px *2 + 1rem + 4px);
  opacity: 1;
}
.profile .pro-menu #menu_bar7:checked ~ #links7 li {
  height: calc(15px *2 + 1rem + 4px);
  opacity: 1;
}

.main-contents-wrap {
  width: 1fr;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.main-contents-wrap .contents-main {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 5px 10px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #999999;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 20% 20% calc(400px - 40%);
  grid-template-columns: 400px 1fr;
}
.main-contents-wrap .contents-main img {
  grid-row: 1/span 3;
  grid-column: 1;
  min-width: 400px;
  max-width: 400px;
  min-height: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
  background-color: black;
}
.main-contents-wrap .contents-main .main-title {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2;
  font-size: 2rem;
  max-height: calc(300px * 0.2);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.main-contents-wrap .contents-main .sub-title {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 2;
  font-size: large;
  max-height: calc(300px * 0.2);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.main-contents-wrap .contents-main .main-text {
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 2;
  max-height: calc(300px * 0.6);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.main-contents-wrap .contents-main a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="jp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TopPage</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="main-all-wrap">
      <div class="index-all-wrap">
        <div class="profile">
          <div class="profile-box">
            <img src="#" class="trim-image-to-circle">
            <div class="pro-name">a</div>
            <div class="pro-text">
              afa
            </div>
            <div class="pro-link">
              <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram-square"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="pro-menu">
            <label for="menu_bar1">label1</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="menu_bar1">
            <ul id="links1">
              <li><a href="#">Link01</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link02</a></li>
            </ul>
            <label for="menu_bar2">label2</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="menu_bar2">
            <ul id="links2">
              <li><a href="#">Link01</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link02</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main-contents-wrap">
          <div class="contents-main">
            <img src="#">
            <div class="main-title">{$maintitle}</div>
            <div class="sub-title">{$subtitle}</div>
            <div class="sub-title">{$subtitle}</div>
            <div class="main-text">{$maintext}</div>
            <a href="#" target="_self"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: 回答内容あってます。ありがとうございます。
align-itemsの知識を深めたいと思います...